# When Using 'cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin', getting errors: 'cat: No file exists' and 'Cannot perform login'

Tags: docker, vagrant, cat, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to use --password-stdin and followed the directions here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

I've looked all over the internet and tried many different things, but nothing is working.

Here is a snapshot of my command line:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGDl2.png)

Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: It literally says what's wrong, the file doesn't exist. So go ahead and create it.

`echo "my_secret_password" > ~/my_password.txt`

Comment: "tried many different things" does not actually do anything at all to help us give you a better answer. Part of the point of telling us _exactly_ what you tried is so we know not to tell you to do things you already did (and, more generally, to get a sense of what direction you've been approaching the problem from). When you just tell us you did "many things" without specifying exactly what any of them are, that doesn't serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `my_password.txt` file in your home directory. If you are new to linux, `cat` outputs the contents of a file, `~` is a shorthand for your home (`/home/vagrant` according to your screenshot), `|` pipes the output of the  left command to the right, and `--password-stdin` makes Docker listen to STDIN, which is written to by the pipe.

Another example is `echo "your very cool password" | docker login --username foo --password-stdin`. If you're only doing this once though, you may as well just login with `--password` though.